# java.lang.Exception: The @Rule 'xyzFolder' must implement MethodRule or TestRule

Tags: java, junit

I have a rule defined for "TemporaryFolder" as below:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder xyzFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
```

and in method:

```
private void testMethod() {
    File testFile = xyzFolder.newFile("test");
}
```

But getting exception as:

```
java.lang.Exception: The @Rule 'xyzFolder' must implement MethodRule or TestRule.
```

Comment: That sounds like a ClassLoader conflict. Do you have more than one version of JUnit in your project?

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With the given information we may not be able to find a solution to your issue, especially if you don't include such information in your OP that the method is invoked from within the actual test-method and similar stuff

Answer (score 0):

A test method should be public to be run as a test case and to correctly interpret the Rule.

```
 @Test
 public void testMethod() {
     File testFile = xyzFolder.newFile("test");
 }
```

http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Test.html

Without seing more details of your code, however, the only other thing I can suggest is to check if you are using the correct version of JUnit and its org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder and not something else.

Comment: Test Method is been called in 
@Test public void testxyz(){
testMethod()
}

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer. If you can show us a bit more of your code, we can try to help

Answer (score 0):

Add "implements TestRule" or "implements MethodRule" to your Class xyzFolder 
Like  "xyzFolder implements TestRule/MethodRule" .
That shall solve the error, and later you have to implement the unimplemented methods according to your needs, Have a look at this 
 for some more details https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/MethodRule.html .