# No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

When start my android app first start `FirstActivity`.
When I click button on `FirstActivity` than start `AddTraderActivity`.
If I press button "**START REQUEST**" in `AddTraderActivity` then I call:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

As result `AddTraderActivity` is destroy and show `FirstActivity`.
Nice.

Now I want to write Espresso's tests for `AddTraderActivityTest` .
Here tests:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@SmallTest
class AddTraderActivityTest {

    @get:Rule
    var addTraderActivity: IntentsTestRule<AddTraderActivity> =
        IntentsTestRule(AddTraderActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun toolBarHeight() {
        onView(withId(R.id.toolBar))
            .check(matches(withHeightResId(R.dimen.tool_bar_height)))
    }

    @Test
    fun buttonStartTextUppercase() {
        onView(withId(R.id.startButton))
            .check(matches(withTextUppercaseResId(R.string.start)))
    }
}
```

As result when I start this tests, then start ONLY `AddTraderActivity` and tests success pass.
Nice.

Now I want to write test for click on button "**START REQUEST**"

Here test:

```kotlin
@Test
fun pressButtonStartProgressBarDisplayed() {
    onView(withId(R.id.baseTextInputEditText)).perform(typeText("BASE_TEST"))
    onView(withId(R.id.quoteTextInputEditText)).perform(typeText("QUOTE_TEST"))
    onView(withId(R.id.startButton)).perform(click())

    onView(withId(R.id.containerProgressBarLayout)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

As result when test run and press button "**START REQUEST**" I get the next error:

Testing started at 16:05 ...

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'com.myproject.AddTraderActivityTest#pressButtonStartProgressBarDisplayed' com.myproject.debug.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.waitForAtLeastOneActivityToBeResumed(RootViewPicker.java:169)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.get(RootViewPicker.java:83)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule.java:77)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:35)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:24)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:10)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.ViewFinderImpl.getView(ViewFinderImpl.java:62)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:276)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:268)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I get this error because in stack has no activity `FirstActivity`, because my test not start it.
So the question is.
How I can **ISOLATE** test only `AddTraderActivity`?

Answer (score 5):

This problem can happen if you migrate from [`ActivityTestRule`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule) to [`ActivityScenarioRule`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule) (or [`ActivityScenario`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario)) and you are trying to test an Activity that has the following code in its `onCreate()` method:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // Workaround the Android bug of multiple Activity task stacks when
  // the app is launched from the Google Play Store. See:
  // https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36941942
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341600/multiple-instances-of-activity-from-google-play-launch
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545889/app-restarts-rather-than-resumes
  if (!isTaskRoot() &&
      getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) &&
      Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
    finish();
    return;
  }

  ...
}
```

This code worked fine with `ActivityTestRule`. But it does not work with `ActivityScenarioRule` or `ActivityScenario`, because it causes errors when the test tries to launch the Activity:

- Either: `"java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?"`
- Or: [`"The @Rule activityScenario must implement MethodRule or TestRule"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756841/java-lang-exception-the-rule-xyzfolder-must-implement-methodrule-or-testrule)

The problem happens because the test will launch the Activity and then immediately close it in `onCreate()`. So you must remove the entire `if` block when using `ActivityScenarioRule` or `ActivityScenario`, or add an additional boolean parameter in the `if` clause, to [check if you are running a UI test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776689/is-it-possible-to-find-out-if-an-android-application-runs-as-part-of-an-instrume).

Answer (score 3):

**Ideally,** you should probably use a separate class for testing separate activity.

But, if you need, you can isolate rules per method using following approach

[EDIT] (**Caution:** You can **NOT** use `@get:Rule` annotation anymore):

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
      // launch desired activity
      var firstActivity: IntentsTestRule<FirstActivity> = IntentsTestRule(FirstActivity::class.java)
      firstActivity.launchActivity(Intent())

      // add tests
      onView(withId(R.id.baseTextInputEditText)).perform(typeText("BASE_TEST"))
      onView(withId(R.id.quoteTextInputEditText)).perform(typeText("QUOTE_TEST"))
}
```

Comment: Now I get error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: #init was called twice in a row. Make sure to call #release after every #init

Comment: Yeah, Man I'm sorry I should have been specific, You can **NOT** use `@get:Rule` annotation anymore. It is getting called for your second method as well. Updating answer.

Comment: I try this :   Rule JvmField var jsonViewActivity = ActivityTestRule(JsonViewActivity::class.java) Intents.init()
        intended(hasComponent(JsonViewActivity::class.java.getName())), but I get error: androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

Comment: what is IntentsTestRule?

Comment: what do you mean "You can NOT use `@get:Rule`"? I'm using it right now

Comment: @Chisko I meant OP cannot use `@get:Rule` anymore, as OP was asking to launch activity specifically, and `@get:Rule` would auto trigger `AddTraderActivity`. So OP should remove it.